# Calculate the coordinates of a point in a line

Tags: geometry, line, detection, point

I have a game represented like this :

[image]

I would like to calculate the coordinates of the point x4,y4.
What I know is : 
y4 = y3, x4 is on the line x1,y1,x2,y2 and the line is 45° (degree)

I tried x4 = y4 - y1 + x1 but it doesn't work very well..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m= (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (y4-y1)/(x4-x1)=1 as slope is 45 degree.
so x4=x1+y4-y1;
substitute y4=y3;
then X4 = x1+y3-y1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/core-algebra-graphing-lines-slope/core-algebra-equation-of-a-line/v/equation-of-a-line-3) should help you to get the right formula.

Should be:

```
m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
b = y2 - m * x2
x4 = (y3 - b) / m
```

Comment: You can simplify the above to `x4 = x1 + (y4-y1)/m`

Answer (score 0):

Since the line is at a 45° angle, dx=dy between two points on the line. Thus:

```
x4 = x1+(y1-y4)
```